# Filter lines of a table that match with your set values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have converted the elements of a column in a set

```
set_genes = set(df['genes'].unique()]
```

And I also have a table (a tsv file) whose one column has values that match my set. I want to extract from this table the lines where values match.

Example

```
print(set_genes)
{'IDA'}
```

print(file)

```
1    1      10  IDA     ID1
1    10     20  IDA     ID2
1    20     30  IDA     ID3
2    1      10  IDB     ID1
2    20     20  IDB     ID2
2    30     30  IDB     ID3
```

Results

```
1    1      10  IDA     ID1
1    10     20  IDA     ID2
1    20     30  IDA     ID3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your TSV file is a dataframe called `df` then use this. Here `column_name` is the name of the column which contains `set_genes`:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'].isin(set_genes)]
```

Sample example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'C2': [1, 10, 20, 1, 10 ,30], 'C3': [10,20,30,10,20,30], 'C4': ['IDA', 'IDA', 'IDA', 'IDB', 'IDB', 'IDB'], 'C5':['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3','ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']})
df
   C1  C2  C3   C4   C5
0   1   1  10  IDA  ID1
1   1  10  20  IDA  ID2
2   1  20  30  IDA  ID3
3   2   1  10  IDB  ID1
4   2  10  20  IDB  ID2
5   2  30  30  IDB  ID3
set_genes = {'IDA'}
df2 = df.loc[df['C4'].isin(set_genes)]
df2
   C1  C2  C3   C4   C5
0   1   1  10  IDA  ID1
1   1  10  20  IDA  ID2
2   1  20  30  IDA  ID3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
  
data = {
    'A':['d', 'q', 's', 'a', 'a'], 
    'genes':['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID4'],  }
  
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# print(df)
# Get the unique values of 'B' column
df.genes.unique()
```

the out put is :

```
array(['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers Abhyuday Vaish and bara-elba but I think that importing the file into padas is not a good idea as the file is massive and the application will be running this many times. I was thinking something like reading lines by lines. If this approach correct?

Comment: @ManuelDominguezBecerra Line by line would be slow as well. How big is your file?

Comment: 600K lines and 49.2 MB

Comment: @ManuelDminguezBecerra No problem it would work.

Comment: Great! I will try after my lunch and I will come back to you soon. Thanks!!